# Tizen app doesn't launch in emulator

Tags: samsung-mobile, tizen, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator

When I try to launch the default navigation sample app in tine emulator I get the following error:

> java.io.IOException: Both an author and a first distributor must be
>   required. Please check your profile infomation.

Comment: Have you created author and distribution cert? You may try deleting old ones, then creating new ones and activating them.